# Allign Mutiple Items with NSLayoutConstraint in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I want to align to CenterX on a view a lot of items.

this code work for 1 item:

```
let control_constraint_ItemAlign = NSLayoutConstraint(item: emailField, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
```

but i want to try a code like that:

```
let control_constraint_ItemAlign = 
NSLayoutConstraint(item:[emailField,passwordField,loginButton],
 attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
 toItem: self.view,
 attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
 multiplier: 1,
 constant: 0)
```

or the only solution is to write a Constraint for each Item?

Comment: You can make a bunch of similar constraints using a `for` loop. You can also reduce the number of constraints you're writing using Visual Format Language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the views:

```
for view in [emailField,passwordField,loginButton] {
    let control_constraint_ItemAlign = 
    NSLayoutConstraint(item:view,
     attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
     relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
     toItem: self.view,
     attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX,
     multiplier: 1,
     constant: 0)
    self.view.addConstraint(control_constraint_ItemAlign)
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass the appropriate option to the visual format language

Comment: this solution work fine, but with only 1 VFL how i can align this items to centerX? ive found only a code without VFL

Answer (score 1):

@Patonz - I'm including this answer because I saw your comment on the accepted answer, I was looking for a solution involving a for-loop + VFL as well.

If I'm not mistaken, I think the correct approach is to just "let it be in the center" rather than trying to force it to be centered.

You can use a loop enumerating your views dictionary, then interpolate the key:

```
let views = [
  "red": redView,
  "blue": blueView,
  "yellow": yellowView,
]

self.statsView.addConstraints(
  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-2-[red(>=10)]-2-[blue(==red)]-2-[yellow(==red)]-2-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

for (index, (key, val)) in enumerate(views) {
  self.statsView.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
      "H:|-60-[\(key)(>=100)]-60-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
}
```

Notice the `>=`. Just set a minimum and let auto layout do its job (expand/fill the remaining space for you). But you can simply remove these and achieve the same effect:

```
self.statsView.addConstraints(
  NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
    "V:|-2-[red]-2-[blue(==red)]-2-[yellow(==red)]-2-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

for (index, (key, val)) in enumerate(views) {
  self.statsView.addConstraints(
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
      "H:|-60-[\(key)]-60-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
}
```

I used colors for visual understanding, you could make your dictionary like this:

```
let views = [
  "email": emailField,
  "password": passwordField,
  "login": loginButton
]
```

Here's a gist of a full example: https://gist.github.com/damionjn/cd6054c6cae770713615

And the resulting code:  http://cl.ly/image/0z0H2C230H3R